# Do "what if" and "how about if" mean the same thing?

Tags: grammar

guys.

Do these two mean the same?

What if we rearrange the meeting?
How about if we rearrange the meeting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***How about...?*** is *extremely* informal, so it might not be appropriate for business-related contexts. There are many other ways of making the same suggestion, but personally I'd suggest you just go for the simplest: ***Shall we** rearrange the meeting?*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica got it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**What if** ....
used to ask what you should do or what the result will be if something happens

> What if this plan of yours fails, what then?

**How about if** ... (informal)
used to mention something that may happen, and ask what should be done if it does happen

> How about if we quit now?

two are to what extent the same, but the latter is informal.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, how about this sentence: "how about if you take my picture?". Does that sound natural?

Comment: @Atika How about= What about = used to make a suggestion about what to do. It seems you used "how about + if you take my picture" here

Comment: okay it's very clear. Thank you very much